# How to add a text to UISearchBar programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have added a `UISearchBar`. In that i need to type a text saying `hello World`. But It should be like a placeholder text, [similar to this;](http://admintell.napco.com/ee/images/uploads/appletell/SearchBariPhone.png)

In the searchBar in the image, you will see the text `Search` displayed. instead of `Search` i want to mention `hello world`.

I tried ;

```
searchBar.text=@"hello World";
```

but this will simply add a text and not a placeholder text as shown in the image.

Answer (score 5):

try using

```
searchBar.placeholder = @"hello world";
```